# Spring Batch Job Param always show zsh : no matches found

Tags: java, spring-batch

I'm learning for the first time how to use spring batch.

I did my spring conf like this :

```java
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class BatchChap4Application {


        @Autowired
        private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

        @Autowired
        private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;


        @Bean
        public Job job(){
            return jobBuilderFactory.get("basicJob").start(step1()).build();
        }

        @Bean
        public Step step1(){
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                    .tasklet((stepContribution, chunkContext) -> {
                        System.out.println("Hello World");
                        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                    }).build();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(BatchChap4Application.class, args);
        }

    }
```

when I run jar manually from command line with string value , it works perfectly.

```java
    java -jar batch.jar executionDate=2021/02/21
```

but when I tried to change the param type from string to date, it always show **zsh: no matches found: executionDate(date)=2021/02/21**

```
    java -jar batch.jar executionDate(date)=2021/02/21
```

got an unexpected output like this :

```
    zsh: no matches found: executionDate(date)=2021/02/21**strong text**
```

I tried to search for error. unfortunately no answer. I'm using macOS for the development.

please help.

Comment: That's curious. Which version of `zsh` do you have? Have you tried with `bash`

Comment: I'm using zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin20.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the parenthesis:

```
java -jar batch.jar executionDate\(date\)=2021/02/21
```

Or pass job parameters between single quotes:

```
java -jar batch.jar 'executionDate(date)=2021/02/21'
```

Comment: thank you !!
the second one works perfectly !!

java -jar batch.jar 'executionDate(date)=2021/02/21'